# C# Properly raise event from background thread and handle it in the UI thread

Tags: c#, event-handling, thread-safety

I have been looking all over the web at examples like this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and all over stackoverflow but I cannot get this to work or find the answer. Or the answer doesn't apply to what I am doing, or there is not enough information in the answer for me to understand how to make this work.

I'm trying to write good code here and avoid Application.DoEvents(). Take a look at the code.

```
private void btnSendQ_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //launch a thread from a button click event
     Thread ManualQueryThread = new Thread(StartManualQueryThread_Thread);
     ManualQueryThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
     ManualQueryThread.IsBackground = true;
     Platform.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "Starting Manual Query Thread.");
     Stats.g_CurrentStatus = "Starting Manual Query Thread.";
     ManualQueryThread.Start();

}

private void StartManualQueryThread_Thread()
{
     try
     {
        //Here work is performed in the background thread populating objects with data.
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
          Platform.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Error in StartManualQueryThread(). The error is: " + e.ToString());
     }
     finally
     {
          //raise event here since the thread has completed
          OnC_FindComplete(EventArgs.Empty);                    
     }
}

    public event EventHandler C_FindComplete;

    protected virtual void OnC_FindComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        //display the gathered information in a datagrid using DisplayC_FindResults(), and enable UI objects.
        EventHandler handler = C_FindComplete;        
        DisplayC_FindResults();
        btnSendQ.Enabled = true;
        btnMove.Enabled = true;
    }
```

The problem is when a release build is created the datagrid gets a null reference exception and does the red X thing because it is still being updated by a background thread. So how do I properly raise an event in a background thread, and process that event in the UI thread to interact with the UI?

Comment: Avoid reinventing the wheel, drop a BackgroundWorker from the toolbox onto your form.  Its RunWorkerCompleted event is raised on the UI thread, you won't get the Red Cross of Failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You'll be able to update your UI in `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Comment: @Svyatski Yes this works well. I have a question. Is this preferred and superior to the method I was attempting? There is so much out there about doing this with raising events and handling them. I actually asked this question of a java developer who used to be a .Net developer for many years at work today, and raising events and handling them was the answer I received.

Comment: @Jake When you work with Windows Forms and you spawn background threads and you want some results returned from them back to your UI, you better stick with BackgroundWorker. You can definitely use threads and tasks from .NET 4.0+, but you'll have to do all the synchronization yourself.